# AlarmManager triggering after 5 minutes and not at the desired time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am using an alarm manager to trigger an intent service every 40 seconds. The below code is how I am triggering the alarm and starting the service. I know that the alarm is not always triggered after 40 seconds exactly and may vary.

But I got a case where the alarm varied a lot and stayed constantly triggering EXACTLY every 5 minutes.

**starting the alarm:**

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
long interval = 40000;
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
```

**alarm receiver:**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
{
     globalVariables.DebugLogging("IsSignedIn: "+GlobalVariables.IsSignedIn+" -DownloadServiceCanStart:- "+GlobalVariables.DownloadServiceCanStart);
     if(GlobalVariables.IsSignedIn)
     {
          if (GlobalVariables.DownloadServiceCanStart)
          {
               GlobalVariables.DownloadServiceCanStart=false;
               Intent intent = new Intent(arg0, DownloadService.class);
               context.startService(intent);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: anyone can help me with this?

Comment: It's an Android bug. I assume you have a Samsung device. A lot of this is manufacturer-dependent and Samsung seems to like to use 5 minute repeats. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211988&thanks=211988&ts=1464886635

Answer (score 1):

The [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is not very precise.

As the official documentation states:

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
>   will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There
>   are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

There is also a minimum interval of 60 seconds. So your 40 second interval would be expanded to 60 seconds.

If you want to run something every 40 seconds exactly, you could investigate this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9539579/503508

Comment: ok thanks ill look into that, i know its not precise but it went to 5 minutes and then precisely every 5 minutes which i found strange.

Comment: This is a bug. See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=211988&thanks=211988&ts=1464886635

Comment: Also, the official documentation is WRONG. Even if you target API < 19, on most Android 5 and all Android 6 devices you don't get the specified behaviour. And it is very manufacturer-specific.